# When was the last time that the Russian Navy was attacked?

Tags: russian-federation, armed-conflict

An answer to a different question got me thinking.  The answer made an assertion about waters which are "hostile" to Russia.  But are there such waters?

Obviously, there could have been some times when Russian ships have been fired upon after Russia initiated hostilities.

But when was the last time that hostilities against the Russian navy occurred because they were initiated by some other country?

Comment: Probably better asked on History SE.

Comment: @Allure has it been *that* long?

Comment: Well, are you counting the Soviet Union? And just military or civilian vessels are included?

Comment: @Fizz "Navy" cannot be civilian.  "Fleet" can be either a military fleet or a civilian fleet.  But a navy is a part of military armed forces of a country. See this [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navy) ("In modern usage 'navy' used alone always denotes a military fleet").  And I think you have to include the USSR because I don't believe RF's Navy has ever been attacked.